Monitor audio output device (Speaker) and feed it into another audio output device (VB-Cable)
I am attempting to create a sort of "soundboard" like application, but one of the primary features I require is monitoring the desktop audio and feeding it into my VB-Cable so I can play it through my microphone. I have been attempting some of my own solutions but all of them seem to lead to dead ends, and I am not sure how else to do it. I have set up a dropdown which shows my active output devices and I can receive the indexes of the output devices to use with libraries such as pyaudio or sounddevice.
I am not sure how to monitor an output device such as a speaker, especially in a way that allows me to feed or play it into another output device.
Here is what my program contains (Two buttons and a dropdown that allows me to select a device):
Screenshot of program
And here is my current attempt which I began heavily using ChatGPT to see if it could find solutions but it was no help at all:
import pyaudio
import threading
import sounddevice as sd

class AudioRedirector:
    def __init__(self, vb_cable_input_index):
        self.vb_cable_input_index = vb_cable_input_index
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.streams_open = False
        self.running = False
        self.thread = None

    def start_audio_redirection(self, speaker_output_index):
        if self.streams_open:
            print("Audio redirection is already running.")
            return

        self.streams_open = True
        self.running = True

        FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
        RATE = 44100
        CHUNK = 1024

        # Get device info to determine number of channels
        speaker_device_info = self.p.get_device_info_by_index(speaker_output_index)
        speaker_channels = speaker_device_info['maxInputChannels']
        if speaker_channels < 1:
            raise ValueError(f"Speaker output device at index {speaker_output_index} does not support input channels.")

        vb_cable_device_info = self.p.get_device_info_by_index(self.vb_cable_input_index)
        vb_cable_channels = vb_cable_device_info['maxOutputChannels']
        if vb_cable_channels < 1:
            raise ValueError(f"VB-Cable input device at index {self.vb_cable_input_index} does not support output channels.")

        # Open speaker output stream for reading
        self.speaker_stream = self.p.open(format=FORMAT,
                                          channels=speaker_channels,
                                          rate=RATE,
                                          input=True,
                                          input_device_index=speaker_output_index,
                                          frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

        # Open VB-Cable input stream for writing
        self.vb_cable_stream = self.p.open(format=FORMAT,
                                           channels=speaker_channels,
                                           rate=RATE,
                                           output=True,
                                           output_device_index=self.vb_cable_input_index,
                                           frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

        def redirect_audio():
            print("Redirecting audio from speaker output to VB-Cable...")
            try:
                while self.running:
                    # Read audio data from the speaker output
                    data = self.speaker_stream.read(CHUNK)

                    # Write audio data to the VB-Cable input
                    self.vb_cable_stream.write(data)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error: {e}")
            finally:
                self.stop_audio_redirection()

        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=redirect_audio)
        self.thread.start()

    def stop_audio_redirection(self):
        if not self.streams_open:
            print("Audio redirection is not running.")
            return

        self.running = False
        self.thread.join()

        # Stop and close the streams
        self.speaker_stream.stop_stream()
        self.speaker_stream.close()
        self.vb_cable_stream.stop_stream()
        self.vb_cable_stream.close()

        self.streams_open = False

        # Terminate PyAudio
        self.p.terminate()
        print("Audio redirection stopped.")

def get_device_index(name):
    devices = sd.query_devices()
    for index, device in enumerate(devices):
        if name in device['name']:
            return index
    return None

audio_redirector = AudioRedirector(get_device_index("CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)"))

def start_monitor(output_name):
    audio_redirector.start_audio_redirection(get_device_index(output_name))

def stop_monitor():
    audio_redirector.stop_audio_redirection()

The VB-Cable is hardcoded as the main output device while the output device I am attempting to monitor is fed into the function start_monitor and using the function get_device_index turns the name of the devices into the corresponding indexes.
The start_monitor and stop_monitor functions are called by the UI already so I just need to figure out how exactly to monitor the given and input the data into the hardcoded VB-Cable.
The solution is very messy and I feel like there has to be some library or method to solve this issue
